# How to animate slide up UIView with AutoLayout?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

this is what I like to achieve:
[image]

I want to perform a slide up animation where a user can slide a UIView2 up, and the UIView2 will stop half-way on the screen.

I know how to present a UIViewControler modally via a UIButton action like so:

```
[self presentViewController:newController animated:NO completion:nil];
```

I also know you need this type of code for animations:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
    [self.customView layoutIfNeeded];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {

}];
```

However, I'm not sure how to achieve this with UIViews, especially since I use AutoLayout for my project and I use constraints to easily support multiple screen sizes.

How can I achieve this without breaking AutoLayout and the constraints I have set up?

Thanks

Answer (score 18, accepted):

What I typically do in this situation is the following.

Add two constraints to your scene. One where `UIView2` is aligned to the bottom of `UIView1`. The second, where it's aligned center of `UIView1` (you'll want to ctrl+drag between the views to add the constraints appropriately). These constraints will initially conflict with one another, and that's fine.

Add `IBOutlet`s to your view controller for the `NSLayoutConstraints` and assign the two constraints we've created to those `IBOutlet`s.

Set the constraint priority on your initial condition to 999 (i.e. constraint priority on align to bottom should be 999). Set the constraint priority on the destination constraint to 998 (i.e. constraint priority on align center is 998). You'll now see that these constraints will no longer conflict. This is because the priority on one constraint overrides the other.

You may see where this is headed now. So when you want to animate `UIView2` between the constraints, swap the priorities and animate!

Code:

```
@interface MyViewController ()
    @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint* constraint0;
    @property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint* constraint1;
@end

- (void)someMethodWhereIWantToAnimate
{
    NSInteger temp = self.constraint0.priority;
    self.constraint0.priority = self.constraint1.priority;
    self.constraint1.priority = temp;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        // Simplest is to use the main ViewController's view
        [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
    }];
}
```

To enable panning and using that to initiate your animation add a Pan Gesture Recognizer to your view controller. Ctrl+drag from `UIView2` to the Pan Gesture Recognizer and set it as a `gestureRecognizer`. Now when you drag on `UIView2`, you'll be able to receive pan events.

Add an IBAction to handle the pan:

```
- (IBAction)onPan:(id)sender
{
}
```

Ctrl+drag from the pan gesture recognizer to the view controller and set `onPan:` as the sent action.

`sender` is actually the pan gesture recognizer itself. So we'll be able to fill out this method to handle a pan and have `UIView2` follow under the user's finger and then initiate the animation when they let go.

Let's start filling out the code:

```
- (IBAction)onPan:(id)sender
{
    UIPanGestureRecognizer* recognizer = (UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender;
    CGPoint translation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
    NSLog(@"State: (%d) Translation in view: (%f, %f)", recognizer.state, translation.x, translation.y);
}
```

If you run with this code, and drag your finger over `UIView2`, you'll see output like this:

```
State: (1) Translation in view: (0.000000, -2.500000)
State: (2) Translation in view: (0.500000, -7.500000)
State: (2) Translation in view: (0.500000, -7.500000)
State: (2) Translation in view: (1.500000, -12.000000)
State: (2) Translation in view: (2.500000, -16.500000)
State: (2) Translation in view: (2.500000, -19.500000)
State: (2) Translation in view: (2.500000, -24.500000)
State: (2) Translation in view: (2.500000, -25.000000)
State: (2) Translation in view: (2.500000, -25.500000)
State: (2) Translation in view: (2.500000, -27.000000)
State: (2) Translation in view: (2.500000, -29.500000)
State: (2) Translation in view: (2.500000, -31.000000)
State: (2) Translation in view: (2.500000, -31.500000)
State: (3) Translation in view: (2.500000, -31.500000)
```

Notice that the values are constantly increasing. We'll want the incremental amount. Notice the state in the log. State (1) is drag start. State (2) is drag changed. State (3) is drag ended. Using this information, we can calculate the delta.

Add a `CGPoint` property to your view controller and add UIView2 as an IBOutlet as well:

```
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint lastTranslation;
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView* uiView2;
```

Finally, let's fill out the final form of our pan method:

```
- (IBAction)onPan:(id)sender
{
    UIPanGestureRecognizer* recognizer = (UIPanGestureRecognizer*)sender;
    CGPoint delta;
    switch(recognizer.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
            // On state begin: delta is the translation. Store it in our member for later user.
            self.lastTranslation = delta = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
            // On state changed: calculate the difference between the translation and our
            // previous translation.
            delta = CGPointApplyAffineTransform([recognizer translationInView:self.view], CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-self.lastTranslation.x, -self.lastTranslation.y));
            self.lastTranslation = [recognizer translationInView:self.view];
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
            // On state ended: Let's just do the constraint animation.
            [self someMethodWhereIWantToAnimate];
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    delta.x = 0; // Forces only vertical drag on the UIView2.
    self.uiView2.center = CGPointApplyAffineTransform(self.uiView2.center, CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(delta.x, delta.y)); // Move our uiView2 based on the delta.
    NSLog(@"State: (%d) Translation in view: (%f, %f)", recognizer.state, delta.x, delta.y);
}
```

This should get you well on your way. You may want to look at tweaking the UIView animation on the constraints a bit based on the pan gesture's 
`velocityInView:` method, but that I'll leave as an exercise.

Comment: I'm assuming constraint1 is the vertical center constraint?...maybe I missed it reading but what constraint does constraint0 correspond to?...bottom?

Comment: Yes, constraint0 would be the constraint for align to bottom. Constraint1 would be the center vertical constraint. @Pangu

Comment: what about the fact that the UIView2 is partially out of the UIView1's window inside of completely inside UIView1?...wouldn't that in itself also create its own constraint conflict?

Comment: No, the priorities are what makes it not conflict. If one priority is higher than the other, there's no conflict between them. @Pangu

Comment: thanks... programmatically how can I detect that UIView2 has been touched and a swipe up gesture is about to occur, as well as a swipe down gesture?

Comment: To do this, I'd add swipe gesture recognizer to your view controller in Interface Builder. Then add an IBAction to handle when the swipe up is recognized. Then, you simply hook up the Swipe Gesture Recognizer to that IBAction. You IBAction can then call `someMethodWhereIWantToAnimate` and your view will animate. I'd add a second gesture recognizer for the swipe down. I'd also set one to be disabled, and toggle the enabled state when the gesture is performed. If you need a more detailed example, let me know and I'll try to find some time tomorrow to update my answer.

Comment: @Pangu, I've added a lot more detail which should get your started on your panning. Panning is a bit more complicated, but it can make a nicer effect.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67576/discussion-between-pangu-and-sandy-chapman).