# iOS 7+ scale animation of new subview with autolayout

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, animation, autolayout

I'm trying to create "pop-in" animation (view height and width should go from 0 to some value) but only thing I've achieved so far is view transiting from left side of the container view to the final position (some code bellow).

Is it even possible to do this animation using only constraints and UIView's animateWithDuration:... method and if it's possible what should I know about it?

Here's some code I use to add new view into container view. I'm using PureLayout for setting up constraints but that shouldn't be problem.

```
//lastView is not nil
UIImageView *lastView = [containerView lastObject];

//Add view to the subview
[containerView addSubview:newView];

//Setup constraints for new view
[newView autoPinEdge:ALEdgeLeft toEdge:ALEdgeRight ofView:lastView withOffset:LABEL_PADDING_HOR];
[newView autoAlignAxisToSuperviewAxis:ALAxisHorizontal];
[newView autoMatchDimension:ALDimensionWidth toDimension:ALDimensionHeight ofView:newView];


//Here I've tried to set height to 0 then layout containerView and then set constraint to the final size but that doesn't work

//Animating this constraint
viewHeightConstraint = [newView autoSetDimension:ALDimensionHeight toSize:50];

// These 2 lines will cause -[updateViewConstraints] to be called again on this view, where the constraints will be adjusted to the new state
[containerView setNeedsUpdateConstraints];
[containerView updateConstraintsIfNeeded];

[UIView animateWithDuration:5.0
                      delay:0.0
     usingSpringWithDamping:0.6
      initialSpringVelocity:0
                    options:0
                 animations:^{
                              [containerView layoutIfNeeded]; // this is what actually causes the views to animate to their new layout
                             }
                 completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                             }];
```

Thank you for any advice!

**EDIT:**

Solution based on answer by almas:

```
//lastView is not nil
UIImageView *lastView = [containerView lastObject];

//Add view to the subview
[containerView addSubview:newView];

//Setup constraints for new view
[newView autoPinEdge:ALEdgeLeft toEdge:ALEdgeRight ofView:lastView withOffset:LABEL_PADDING_HOR];
[newView autoAlignAxisToSuperviewAxis:ALAxisHorizontal];
[newView autoMatchDimension:ALDimensionWidth toDimension:ALDimensionHeight ofView:newView];


//Here I've tried to set height to 0 then layout containerView and then set constraint to the final size but that doesn't work

//Animating this constraint
viewHeightConstraint = [newView autoSetDimension:ALDimensionHeight toSize:50];

newView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0, 0);

CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animation];
anim.keyPath = @"transform.scale";
anim.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0];
anim.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
anim.duration = 1.0;
anim.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
anim.removedOnCompletion = NO;
anim.fillMode = kCAFillModeBoth;
anim.delegate = self;
[newView.layer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"scaleIn"];

newView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 1, 1);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could probably just animate the transform of the layer.
Set it to something like :  `CGAffineTransformScale(CGAffineTransformIdentity, 0, 0);`
and then animate to:

```
CGAffineTransformIdentity
```

You can find more example here: http://www.objc.io/issues/12-animations/animations-explained/

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a solution I suggested elsewhere.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27608611/1270148) The basic idea is that you animate between constraints by swapping their priorities and then call your animate block where you simply make a call to update your view's sublayers. I use this all the time and it should save you from having to deal with CALayers or pixel offset values.